# Popup Keyboard in Custom Keyboard

Tags: android, keyboard, android-softkeyboard

I'm developing a soft keyboard for android.. I followed [this tutorial](http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/create-a-custom-keyboard-on-android--cms-22615).. It works fine.. But I need to make the preview of the keyboard key appear as a keyboard.. I have done that through this code :

```
    <Key android:codes="97" android:keyLabel="a" android:keyEdgeFlags="left" android:popupCharacters="aA" android:popupKeyboard="@layout/preview"/>
```

preview.xml :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.inputmethodservice.Keyboard xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:keyWidth="8%p"
    android:keyHeight="8%p"
   >
</android.inputmethodservice.Keyboard>
```

I get the preview as a keyboard with the letters 'a' and 'A' and 'X' for exit and that's fine.. But when I try to click any of these letters nothing happens.. and when I click 'X' it exits..

Any Idea ?

Comment: Hello, friend. Have you found a solution for changing appearance of android:popupKeyboard?

Answer (score 0):

You need to change you preview.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Keyboard xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      android:keyWidth="40dp"
      android:horizontalGap="0px"
      android:verticalGap="0px"
      android:keyHeight="50dp" >
</Keyboard>
```